# Exporting multiple shapefiles into FGDB with ArcPy (Python)?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting the error?

I am trying to export multiple shapefiles to a single File Geodatabase.

```py
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = r"W:/gis/condition assessment/quad c/quad c shapefile"
>>> in_features = ["Cond_Asses_Ditch_C.shp", "Cond_Assess_Inlet_C.shp", "Cond_Assess_Manhole_C.shp", "Cond_Assess_Outlet_C.shp"]
>>> out_location = r"X:/data.gdb"
>>> arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features, out_location)
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1694, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Comment: `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` takes a single feature class as input, you need to loop over your list and do one at a time.  Also check the docs because you need to supply more to that function:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

Comment: @mikewatt Thanks. So what you're saying is that I actually need to call the FeatureClasstoFeatureClass_conversion() tool four separate times?

Comment: @mikewatt I think you have enough in you comment to be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = r'X:\Quab B Shapefile'
>>> shpList = [r'X:\Quab B Shapefile\Ditch_QuadB_CondAssess.shp', r'X:\Quab B Shapefile\Inlet_QuadB_CondAssess.shp', r'X:\Quab B Shapefile\Manhole_QuadB_CondAssess.shp', r'X:\Quab B Shapefile\Outlet_QuadB_CondAssess.shp']
>>> for featureclass in shpList:
...     outPath = r'X:\data.gdb'
...     outName = arcpy.Describe(featureclass).baseName
...     arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(featureclass, outPath, outName)
...     
>>>
```